# Are questions about how to code on the SO Data Explorer on topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope, data-explorer

Looking to do some research on SO so I can pose a meta-question (if my hunch is right), but I'm not familiar with the language of the data explorer.  Can I ask questions on how to implement the query to find data on SO so I can post a question on MSO about my query?  If it is on topic, are there any specific tags I should use?

Comment: You can explore the data on Data Explorer using SQL, it's SQL Server backend so it supports MS-SQL syntax and functions. MSE is the proper place for SEDE specific questions, since it contains data of all sites.

Comment: If you have a question about SQL Server, you should still ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Questions about *Transact SQL*, the SQL dialect used by the SEDE server, are on-topic; see the [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) tag, for example.

Questions about the SEDE *schema* are not; ask those on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) instead.

In other words, if the question can be applied to *any* SQL Server, not just to the SEDE dataset, it is on-topic. If the question is *closely coupled to the SEDE dataset*, it is off-topic.

Question about how to use `UNION` or `CAST` or date formats? *On topic*. How to select all answers with positive score from 3 months ago? *Off topic*. Etc.

Comment: When you say "off topic" you mean off-topic for SO, but on topic for MSE, correct?

Comment: @wnnmaw: correct; I'm responding to your question title here :-)